# Convexity of $g(f(x))$ when $g$ is decreasing and $f$ is concave.

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I haven't been able to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated!

> Prove or give a counter example: For any $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and any $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if $f$ is
>   concave and $g$ is a decreasing function, then $g\circ f$ is a convex function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a convex function is necessarily continuous, so can you come up with an example where $g\circ f$ isn't even continuous?

Answer (score 0):

A continuous and differentiable (and even smooth) example: let $f(x) = -0.01x^2$ and $g(x) = -\sin(x)-x$. This makes $$g(f(x)) = -\sin(-0.01x^2)-(-0.01x^2) = \sin(0.01x^2) + 0.01x^2$$Is this function non-convex? The second derivative is
$$
[g(f(x))]'' = 0.02x\cos(0.01x^2) + 0.02x\\
= 0.02\cos(0.01x^2)  -0.02x^2\sin(0.01x^2) + 0.02
$$
and we note that for $x$ which fulfill $0.01x^2 = \frac\pi2 + 2n\pi$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$, the $\cos$ term vanishes, and $g(f(x)) = -0.02x^2 + 0.02 = -\pi - 4n\pi + 0.02$, which is negative for any natural $n$.

The moral here is that $f$, while strictly concave, has barely any curvature to it, and $g$, while decreasing, has a lot of variation in the *rate* of decreasing. This variation in the slope of $g$ is enough to outweigh the slight concaveness of $f$ and make $g(f(x))$ non-convex.